# Convert or Parse Java Pojo to MimeMessage

Tags: java, pojo, mime-message

Following code for you reference. Convert Pojo to MimeMessage in Java
 Am trying to sent Email Using Javax Mail Following code am used ,It's not converting InputStream to MimeMessage. All Mimemessage Attributes was null.

```
public class MailMessage
{
    private String fromName;
    private String fromAddress;
    private String subject;
    private String body;
    private boolean attachment;
    private String attachmentName;
    private String attachmentContent;
    private String attachmentType;
    private List<MailRecipient> mailRecipients;
}

public class sentEmail 
{
  public static void main(String args[])    
  {
     MailMessage MailMessage = new new MailMessage();
     List<MailRecipient> mailRecipients = new ArrayList<MailRecipient>();
     MailRecipient mailRecipient = new MailRecipient();
     MailRecipientType mailRecipientType = new MailRecipientType();
     byte[] bytes = null;           
     ByteArrayOutputStream bos = null;
     ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

     mailMessage.setFromName("Sender Name");         
     mailMessage.setFromAddress("xxx@gmail.com");                
     mailMessage.setSubject("Maile Subject");                
     mailMessage.setBody(rs.getString("Hi This is testing email"));

     mailRecipient.setName("Recipient_name");
     mailRecipient.setAddress("yyyy@gmail.com");

     mailRecipientType.setName("TO");

     mailRecipients.add(mailRecipient);
     mailMessage.setMailRecipients(mailRecipients);

     bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
     oos.writeObject(mailMessage);
     oos.flush();
     bytes = bos.toByteArray();

     javax.mail.Session session =javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
     InputStream str = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
     Transport transport = session.getTransport();
     MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session, str);

      transport.connect("url", "userName",  "Password");



      transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
}
```

I am using the Following code.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
MailMessage MailMessage = new new MailMessage();
```

to

```
MailMessage mailMessage = new new MailMessage(); // object name start with small m because you are using it onward.
```

why don't you directly set the parameters in `MimeMessage`? like

```
 MimeMessage message= new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom("Sender Name");
    message.setFrom("xxx@gmail.com");
    message.setSubject("Maile Subject");
    message.setContent(rs.getString("Hi This is testing email"));
    //Rest of your code

   // and send
```